# Jquery load ignoring object and not posting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange situation where I am loading some content into a modal using jQuery load(). This is working perfectly in development but on the production server, the object is being ignored and only sending a GET request. I've checked the `typeof` object which is successful and tried other variations in the second parameter of the load method. Never had this before.

```
var $modal = $('#ajax-modal');


        $('body').modalmanager('loading');

        //_token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

        setTimeout(function(){

            var _post = {ajax:true, lead:lead, type:type };

            $modal.load('leads/action/', _post, function(){


          });
        }, 1000);
```

Headers:

```
Request URL:http://mydomain/leads/action
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

I'm also getting `Provisional headers are shown` in Chrome.

The script should `POST` to the url and load the data into the modal. Below are the headers sent when I'm on my local server:

```
ajax:true
lead:4273
type:reminder
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You need a POST request or is fine a GET request?

Comment: are you using web API? @jhodgson4

Comment: may be the issue is the query string exceeds the limit? @jhodgson4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Redirection problem: When you `POST` your request to `leads/action/` your server redirects it to `leads/action` with a `GET` request. You can resolve this by removing the trailing slash:

```
$modal.load('leads/action', _post, function(){
                       //^ Here

});
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I'll give it a try, thank you! Really struggled to troubleshoot this one!

Comment: Worked a treat! Do you have any advice on how I would of troubleshooted this? Or is it just an experience thing? @Ismail RBOUH

Comment: I had this problem once! the clue was the `Request URL`.  Browser 'DevTools' is your friend ;)